# In Vim, how can I switch the functionality of 'i', 'j', 'k' and 'h'

Tags: vim

I am 5 or so weeks into learning Vim for development, and while things are starting to sink in, I have one personal issue that is frustratingly still tripping me up.

I am constantly using 'i' to move 'up.'  'k' is down, 'j' and 'l' are left and right respectively.

I know this all comes from playing too many years of PC games where these were direction movements. Honestly, I don't want to fight it anymore, and I would rather do what is extremely natural for me. How can I remap these so the above are the direction movements and 'h' is insert?

2 issues: How can I permanently store these in my local settings for development on my own machine, and how can I also quickly switch these when I am on someone else's machine for the time I am working on it. I mean, is there a set of commands that I can invoke and then they be erased when I shut Vim down?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put this in a file called `~/.vimrc`:

```
noremap i k
noremap k j
noremap j h
noremap h i
```

If you're using vim on someone else's computer, you can type the same four commands at the prompt (type `:` before each, and enter after each), and the settings will apply for 1 session only.

Also, `no` is short for `noremap`, so you can shorten the whole sequence to

```
:no i k<enter>:no k j<enter>:no j h<enter>:no h i<enter>
```

when you're using someone else's computer.

Answer (score 10):

**DON'T DO THAT MAPPING! It is even worse than using arrow keys**

first of all, I would suggest you learning the vim way to move your cursor.

Back to your question, remapping `h,j,k,l` is easy. However, it makes no sense to do those mapping (and you shouldn't do it), it won't make you work faster, it just drives you crazy when you use your vim. You know, editing with vim doesn't mean

- in NORMAL mode, just do cursor moving
- entering INSERT mode, do actual text editing
- back to NORMAL mode to save the file

There are a lot of vim magic you could do in `NORMAL` mode (that's why it was called `NORMAL`). with your mapping, you will really have headache when you want to apply those. Let's take an example. Say you have already set mappings for your needs. `i,j,k and h`. We have a line:

```
function foo (String arg)
```

when your cursor is between `(`and `)`, you could type `ci(` to change the stuff in brackets. However your `i` means `k`.  What would happen? the current line and the line above it will be removed!! Well you could say, you will remember to type `chw, dhw,ch(,dhw...` So you have to remap those keys also in your mind. :)

Also when you want to "borrow" someone else's `.vimrc`, or use some plugins, you will have problem too.

You see the point by the simple example above. So please think it twice before you remap those basic keys.

Comment: Good points above, thank you for that. Transitioning from the arrow keys and Counterstrike is killing me :) But I'll dig in a little harder. I thought I was simply moving around more efficiently, but if I am doing more harm than good for future, more advanced, Vim editing, certainly don't want that.

Comment: to be honest, I cannot imagine that when you sit in front of your vim and press h,j,k,l to move cursor, it will make you feel playing CS or other games....  don't you think about the codes or text you are editing. anyway.. the answer is just my 2 cents.

Comment: Play Nethack for couple weeks instead.

Comment: First, I agree totally with the advice in the answer. But if you use correct mapping to use `i` for `up`, then `i` will still mean "expand" (or what to call it) in the sequence `ci(`. I don't want to write it out here, it's better that OP don't do the mappings :) But it can be good to know for another situation.